# Feature detection of foreignObject in SVG

Tags: svg, feature-detection

I am using the foreignObject element in SVG, however IE9 does not support this element. I am looking at a way the detect this feature. Modernizr does not detect this feature and it seems I can not use createSVGForeignObject (not available on SVGSVGElement) like they do for rectangle (createSVGRect).

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear: `createSVGRect()` doesn't create a rect element, it creates a rect object. To create elements just use `document.createElementNS(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work if you want to use foreignObject because it integrates html content...

```
<switch>
  <g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <foreignObject >
    </foreignObject>
  </g>
  <text font-size="10" font-family="Verdana">
     No foreignObject
  </text>
</switch>
```

The requiredExtensions part [proposed to w3c](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-svg-wg/2008JulSep/0299.html#start299) and [this was their response](http://www.w3.org/2008/09/16-svg-minutes.html#item03). Firefox does implement this, but I havent tested anything else though. You may be able to get away with just the requiredFeatures attribute as Erik suggests.

If you want to test in javascript try

```
var supported = document.implementation.hasFeature("http://w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility", "1.1"); –
```

Comment: `http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility` is the featurestring defined in SVG 1.1 for the foreignObject element, if that's what you want to test. You can list several values in requiredExtensions (space-separated).

Comment: Thanks for your help. This technic provides an alternate rendering in case user agent support is not available. However, I was looking for a Javascript solution (for conditional code). That is what I would be using `/SVGForeignObject/.test(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg').appendChild(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject')).toString())`

Comment: Simply `typeof SVGForeignObjectElement !== 'undefined'` would do the job as well.

Comment: +1 for `document.implementation.hasFeature("w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility","1.1")`

Comment: This answer works for me, except can you please update the hasFeature url (remove the extra www.).

Comment: I edited the answer but hasFeature now returns true in Chrome and Firefox whatever you pass in. You can't do feature detection that way any more.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to test this feature in JS, the following was borrowed from a recent commit to modernizr (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/commit/ee836f083f29a9e634df731400027c24630a75f3):

```
        var toStringFnc = ({}).toString;
        Modernizr.addTest('svgforeignobject', function() {
            return !!document.createElementNS &&
                /SVGForeignObject/.test(toStringFnc.call(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject')));
        });
```